# How to make code coverage threshold on gitlab or in YAML

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab, code-coverage, threshold

I've configured CI on gitlab but now I need to configure code coverage threshold. How can I do this? Is is possible to configure it using gitlab or I need to write python script for it? I've checked yaml file attributes and I haven't found it. Could you help me?